# A list of maps as argument

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I created a schema that looks as follow:

```
schema "countries" do

    field :code, :string
    field :en, :string
    field :de, :string
    field :it, :string
    field :fr, :string

    timestamps

  end
```

Now a I want to create changeset function that would accept a list of map. How can I define it? Is this right(I would say it is wrong):

def changeset_all(model, []) do

Then how can I validate if the passed parameter contains maps or not?

The second question is, how can I loop through the list of maps, that after I would get a changeset of all pass values? I would do like this:

```
def changeset_all(model, [params]) do

  for param <- [params] do
      model
      |> cast(param, [:code, :en, :de, :it, :fr])
      |> validate_required([:code, :en])
      |> validate_length(:code, max: 3)
      |> unique_constraint(:code)
    end
  end
```

I hope my questions are clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def changeset_all(model, [params]) do` will only accept a list of 1 element. To accept any lists, you can do:

```
def changeset_all(model, params) when is_list(params) do
```

To create a list of changesets, just do `for param <- params`. The final code should look like:

```
def changeset_all(model, params) when is_list(params) do
  for param <- params do
    model
    |> cast(param, [:code, :en, :de, :it, :fr])
    |> validate_required([:code, :en])
    |> validate_length(:code, max: 3)
    |> unique_constraint(:code)
  end
end
```

> Then how can I validate if the passed parameter contains maps or not?

You don't really need to do this as if you pass an invalid parameter, `cast` will handle throwing an error. If you want to do this, you can loop through the list and use `if` to check if it's a map:

```
for param <- params
  if !is_map(param) do
    raise "#{param} is not a map"
  end
end

for param <- params do
  # changeset stuff
end
```

---

I would recommend creating a `changeset/2` function separately and then calling it using `Enum.map` in `changeset_all/2`:

```
def changeset(model, params) do
  model
  |> cast(params, [:code, :en, :de, :it, :fr])
  |> validate_required([:code, :en])
  |> validate_length(:code, max: 3)
  |> unique_constraint(:code)
end

def changeset_all(model, list) do
  list |> Enum.map(fn params -> changeset(model, params) end)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it tonight and let you know.